# Ошибка в python 3.9

Tags: python

Помогите у меня ошибка `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'str' and 'int' on line 32`

Вот код:

```py
import random
import time


player_score = 0
pc_score = 0
rounds = 3

#Логика игры
while True:
    if rounds <=0:
        break
    player = input('Выберите: Камень, ножницы, бумага')
    pc = random.randint(1,3)
    if pc == 1:
        pc = 'Камень'
    elif pc == 2:
        pc = 'Ножницы'
    elif pc == 3:
        pc = 'Бумага'


    if player == comp:
        print("Ничья")
    elif (player == 'Камень' and pc == 'Ножницы') or (player == 'Ножницы' and pc == 'Бумага') or (player == 'Бумага' and pc == 'Камень'):
        print('Игрок побеждает!')
        player_score += 1
    else:
        print('Компьютер побеждает!')
        pc_score += 1
        rounds -= 1 
    print('Конец игры')
    print('Компьютер:' + ' ' + pc_score)
    print('Игрок:' + ' ' + player_score)
```

Answer (score 2):

Как то так:

```
if pc == 1:
    c = 'Камень'
elif pc == 2:
    c = 'Ножницы'
elif pc == 3:
    c = 'Бумага'
pc = c
```

код:

```
import random

player_score = 0
pc_score = 0
rounds = 1

while rounds < 4:
    print(f"Раунд {rounds}")
    player = input('Выберите: 1-Камень, 2-ножницы, 3-бумага')
    dct = {1: 'Камень', 2: 'Ножницы', 3: 'Бумага'}
    player = dct[player]
    pc = random.choice(['Камень', 'Ножницы', 'Бумага'])
    if player == pc:
        print("Ничья")
    elif (player == 'Камень' and pc == 'Ножницы') or (player == 'Ножницы' and pc == 'Бумага') or (
            player == 'Бумага' and pc == 'Камень'):
        print('Игрок побеждает!')
        player_score += 1
    else:
        print('Компьютер побеждает!')
        pc_score += 1
    rounds += 1
print('Конец игры')
print('Компьютер Игрок')
print(f'{pc_score:5} {player_score:7}')
```

вывод:

```
Раунд 1
Игрок побеждает!
Раунд 2
Компьютер побеждает!
Раунд 3
Компьютер побеждает!
Конец игры
Компьютер Игрок
    2       1
```